# how to rewrite the snippet with inject

Tags: ruby

I think the variable `lst` is repeating so many times,

I want to write the snippet with inject

I replaced

```
    lst = []
    settings.each do | value_pair|
```

with

`settings.inject([]) do |lst, value_pair|`

But I got some errors, it seems there are not equivalent ?

### code

```
  def get_hash(settings)
    lst = []
    settings.each do | value_pair|
      begin
        key,v = value_pair[0], value_pair[1] # ["quant", "3"]
        case key
        when "codec"
          lst << {"codec" => v}
        else
          lst.last[key] = v
        end
      rescue Exception => e
        p e
      end
    end
    return lst
  end
```

### Rewrite with inject version

```
  def get_hash(settings)
    lst =  settings.inject([]) do | lst, value_pair|
      begin
        key,v = value_pair[0], value_pair[1] # ["quant", "3"]
        case key
        when "codec"
          lst << {"codec" => v}
        else
          lst.last[key] = v
        end
      rescue Exception => e
        p e
      end
    end
    return lst
  end
```

### Errors

```
    #<IndexError: string not matched>
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<IndexError: string not matched>>
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<NoMethodError:0x007ffcb77b4768>>
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<NoMethodError:0x007ffcb77b4538>>
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<NoMethodError:0x007ffcb77b41f0>>
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<NoMethodError:0x007ffcb77afd08>>
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<NoMethodError:0x007ffcb77af808>>
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for #<NoMethodError:0x007ffcb77af150>>
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<NoMethodError:0x007ffcb77ae9f8>>
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<NoMethodError:0x007ffcb77ae228>>
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<NoMethodError:0x007ffcb77ad968>>
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<NoMethodError:0x007ffcb77acc70>>
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<NoMethodError:0x007ffcb77a7d60>>
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<NoMethodError:0x007ffcb77a71d0>>
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<NoMethodError:0x007ffcb77a6438>>
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<NoMethodError:0x007ffcb77a56c8>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the equivalent inject statement:

```
 def get_hash(settings)
    result = settings.inject([]) do |lst, value_pair|
      begin
        key,v = value_pair[0], value_pair[1] # ["quant", "3"]
        case key
        when "codec"
          lst << {"codec" => v}
        else
          lst.last[key] = v
        end
      rescue Exception => e
        p e
      end
      lst # << RETURN lst in the end of inject block
    end
    return result
  end
```

You have to return the aggregated object in the end of the inject block.

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed that the only thing that would raise an exception is that `lst` is empty when the  line `lst.last[key] = v` is executed. If that's not correct, please let me know. It's too bad you didn't include some data for testing.

```
def get_hash(settings)
  settings.inject([]) do |lst, (key, v)|
    if key == "codec"
      lst << {"codec" => v}
    else
      if lst.empty?
        p "'#{lst.last} = #{v}' was attempted when lst = []"
      else
        lst.last[key] = v
      end
    end
    lst
  end
end
```